# EventListener still on after that browser has been manually closed? (Puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, eventemitter

I noticed that when you manually close a browser launched with Puppeteer, it persists in occupying memory. I tried eleven times to launch a browser instance and then closing it manually (clicking the cross on the top corner of the browser interface), but on the eleventh attempt I get the warning

```
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20424) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I tried to manage this problem by killing the child process of the browser (identified by its pid) when the event "disconnected" occurs, but it doesn't work:

```
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                headless:false,
                devtools:false,       
            })
            page = (await browser.pages())[0];
            const browserPid = browser.process().pid;

            browser.on('disconnected', () => {
                process.kill(browserPid)
            })
```

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You can set a maximum of listeners by adding `Infinity` value (or any number you prefer) to `process.setMaxListeners()` before your puppeteer main script:

```js
process.setMaxListeners(Infinity)
```

In general you can avoid launching this many chromium instances - if your use case allows it - by reusing the same browser instance. You can create a websocket endpoint with [`browser.wsEndpoint`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-browserwsendpoint) then instead of new `puppeteer.launch`-s you can [`puppeteer.connect`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-puppeteerconnectoptions) to the existing wsEndpoint by using the `browserWSEndpoint` option.

**Example:**

```js
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  const browserWSEndpoint = await browser.wsEndpoint()
  [...]

  const browser2 = await puppeteer.connect({ browserWSEndpoint })
```

Comment: Correct, but I need to launch and close manually fresh new browser instances. On the other hand, i don't want to turn off the warning but i want to shut down the listeners since that they slow down the main process

Comment: If you only need to close the processes to gain more resources (CPU I suppose), then why `browser.close()` is not an option? It would totally prevent the memory leak.

Comment: Because I need to close MANUALLY the browser

Comment: well, then OK 